# Ubuntu 22.04 recent update caused inability to connect to a network from BOTH ethernet cable and Wifi. Please help me get it working again

Tags: networking, 22.04

After restarting from a automatic update there is no network connection wired or wifi, but I had both before.

I was looking at similar questions and attempted to solve it similarly, but no luck.

Here is some information I think is useful for the PC as-is presently. Forgive me I am new to AskUbuntu so I'm hand typing this carefully and slowly.

lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtech Simiconductor Co., LTd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

I also noticed lcpci has this line too (among many others):

lspci
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realteck Simiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 Pci Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

This is a miniPC mele Quieter 2Q.

sudo lshw -class network

```
 *-network DISABLED
 description: Ethernet interface
 product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
 vendor: Realtech Simiconductor Co., Ltd.
 Physical id: 0
 bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
 logical name: enp2s0
 version: 15
 ...
 configuration: breadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic latency=0 link=0 multicast=yes
 *-network DISABLED
 description: Wireless interface
 product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
 vendor: realtek Simiconductor
 ...
 configuration: breadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic
```

I managed to use CubeGet to download the packages and dependencies for the package rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu11-0.22.04.1_all.deb
and install it with:

```
 sudo dpkg -i '/path/MyPackage1.deb' '/path/MyPackage2.deb' ...
```

Because CubeGet failed to install it with no install log file created. So I just did the above. It did unpack etc. It did output that it skipped a step during the install because something did not match the kernal and the kernal config. I don't know if that is important.

I restarted, no ethernet, no Wifi. I just need one to work, but both is better.
I'm at the end of my ability. I can reinstall if needed. But will it just happen again after the update installs again?

Comment: Look at `service NetworkManager status`, `ip link;ip route`. Read `man networkmanager ip ip-route ip-link`.

Answer (score 0):

Networking was disabled through the network manager. Command line nmcli
This worked for me:

```
 sudo nmcli networking on
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Waltinator. Your comment was helpful.